# US citizen visiting Canada with a passport expiring in 5 months

Tags: passports, canada, us-citizens

I’m going to Canada and my passport  will expire in five months. Will this be OK? I cannot find the answer. I know some countries require it to be no more than six months before expiration. But I know some countries have different rules

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, this will be OK**

U.S. Governement's website states this for US Citizens traveling to Canada.

> PASSPORT VALIDITY:
>
> Valid at time of entry.

Source: [travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html)

And the Canadian Government's website also does not list any validity period requirements for US citizens.

> If you are a citizen of the United States, you need a passport to fly to or transit through a Canadian airport, but not to enter Canada by land or by boat. You must carry proof of your citizenship, such as a birth certificate, certificate of citizenship or naturalization, or a Certificate of Indian Status, as well as photo identification.

Source: [travel.gc.ca](https://travel.gc.ca/returning/travelling-to-canada)